# Having a banner on top of an image in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, image, outlook, haml

I want to have a banner on top of my image (overlapped on top of the image) when I am sending that image via email. Something like this:
[image]

This is my haml code:

```
    %table.inline-block{align:'left'}
      %tbody
        %tr
          %td.w30{width: '15'}
          %td#wrap
            - if cat.present?
                .banner Updated Price
                = image_tag("#{cat.photos}")
```

And these are related css files:

```
#wrap {
  position:relative;
  width: 195px;
  height: 165px;
  }

.banner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #05c3de;
  color:white
  }
```

The problem is Microsoft Outlook does not understand the Css Position: 'Absolute' or Position: 'Relative', and so it puts the banner on top of the image (Not overlapped)

So I changed the haml code as below:

```
    %table.inline-block{align:'left'}
      %tbody
        %tr
          %td.w30{width: '15'}
          %td#wrap
            - if cat.present?
              <!--[if mso]>
              <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
              <v:fill type="tile" src="#{property.photos.first.thumbnail}"/>
              </v:background>
              <![endif]-->
              <!--[if !mso]>
              .banner Updated Price
              = image_tag("#{cat.photos}")
              <![endif]-->
```

I still have the same problem, the image is displayed like this in Outlook:
[image]

Any ideas about how to fix it? Appreciate any help or any ideas.
Thanks,
Venus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after spending lots of time on email templates I realised that I should use tables. (position absolute and relative are not rendered in gmail and outlook templates and so I can't overlap images on top of each other).

```
        - if cat.present?
           <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
              %table{style: "background-image: url('#{cat.photos.first.thumbnail}'); width: 195px; height: 165px;"}
                  %tbody
                    %tr
                      %td.banner
                        Updated price  
           <!--<![endif]-->

                :plain
                  <!--[if mso]>
                  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="position:relative;width:195px;height:165px;z-index:1" fillcolor="#E8E8E8">
                  <v:fill type="frame" src="#{property.photos.first.thumbnail}"/>
                  <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                  </v:textbox>
                  </v:rect>
                  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="v-text-anchor:middle;width:195px;position:relative;width:195px;height:30px;z-index:2;v-text-anchor:middle;" fillcolor="#05c3de">Zero
                  <v:textbox inset="50px, 5px, 50px, 5px">
                  <span style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;margin-left: 50px;">Updated price</span>
                  </v:textbox>
                  </v:rect>
                  <![endif]-->
```

In this approach I used an image as a table background and use a banner as a table row to cover the background.
I really don't like this approach since the image should not just be a css background (should be a html image tag ), and I want to set an 'alt' property for that image.

Unfortunately I tried lots of other approaches and couldn't come up with any other solutions. :)
Let me know if you have any other ideas.

Cheers,